# Upgrading to react-navigation v5 from v3

Tags: react-native, react-navigation

I am currently using react-navigation v3, and am looking to upgrade to v5. This blog article mentions an upgrade path from v4 to v5 https://reactnavigation.org/docs/en/upgrading-from-4.x.html.

My question is - what is the best way of upgrading, do I need to first upgrade to v4, or since the change is so big can I upgrade directly to v5? Would hate to spend the time upgrading to v4 if it's not necessary.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Answer provided by @satya164 (react-navigation lead) via twitter DM:

Upgrading from 3 to 4 is mostly mechanical, so it wouldn't change much.

I recommend upgrading to latest version of stack navigator first though as it has some helpful warnings about the changes and the options are same for v5

If you have a large app, you can stay on v4, it'll be supported for a while. If you don't have many navigators, you can upgrade to v5 directly. but note that there are many breaking changes, so go through the upgrade guide if you want to do that.

If you use web, then you might want to wait a little while since we're still working in web support

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to use v5 then you can skip v4 and can directly move to v5. Since there is no more structural changes in v3 to v4, so if you first move v3 to v4 then it the wast of time, because there are only some props changes will get. So, I think you should move directly to v5.

Comment: What about upgrading from React Navigation 3 to RN6? Shall I upgrade directly from 3->6 OR the incremental upgrade is the preferred way to go, i.e., 3->4->5->6? Many thanks!! @IonicBurger

Comment: Same question of @BehnamKamrani!

Comment: Generally 5 > 6 is pretty minor, so would suggest going from 3 > 5 first. That is what I did in my team.